# Consume WCF service within ASP.NET webforms application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, webforms

I am trying to write a webforms application that can consume a wcf service. The WCF service is used by windows application as well as a windows service I created. Both can consume the WCF service fine, my website however cannot when being deployed. I've followed guides on how to properly consume a web service within asp.net. I've created the client and called the function in the code behind. My bindings seem to be correct.

I've researched and it shows me to enable Tls and I have and it still will not worked.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

I've added the above code in my global.asax.vb file as well as before calling my web service function.

What am I missing here? This is my error message:

```
[CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
https://myserviceD.net/Service.svc.This could be due to the fact that the
server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case.
This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the
client and the server.]
```

Here is my WCF config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And a winforms config file that successfully consumes the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://myserviceD.net/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" contract="myserviceD.ServiceReference.IService"
        name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Adding config file from my web app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https:///myserviceD.net/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" contract="myserviceD.net.ServiceReference.IService"
        name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was modifying the host file and I had the wrong ip mapped to domain name

Answer (score 0):

The error details mainly indicate that there is something wrong with the service, such as the service is not working properly over https.
How do you call the service on the client-side? In the other application which can consume the service properly what is the auto-generated configuration? I suspect there is something wrong with the service over HTTPS. It might only work over HTTP. Besides, this issue has nothing to do with the TLS version, The OS will decide on the TLS version.
I would like to know the WCF configuration on the server-side and the client configuration that can call the service properly.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you for the help, will add the config files for both shortly in the main question. Calling the service is basically adding a reference to the WCF service, then making a serviceclient object in the code-behind and calling the web service methods through the client. The same approach is in the winforms and service applications.

Comment: From the WinForm client configuration, the service works properly over HTTPS. Thereby the invocation is well performed. 
Please attempt to add the service reference again, check whether the client configuration is consistent with the other configuration. finally, invoke the service.

Comment: Besides, I have made a successful call to the URL mentioned in the error details. It indeed works well over the https protocol and created by the Basichttpsbinding.

Comment: I have made anew application adding the service reference and I am still getting that error, I've tried removing and readding.

Comment: Another thing to note, the service works fine when debugging from VS, however when I deploy the site on a web server I get the same error. Also the Web service and web application are on the same server.

Comment: Haven't heard back in a while, is this problem fixable?

Comment: It seems that the issue is more relates to the website instead of the WCF service.
What is your binding information of you site and WCF project? we have to set up an https binding to the WCF service and trust the WCF certificate, namely install the certificate in the localCA.

Comment: adding my bindings for web application. works when deployed from visual studio. will error when deployed on web server

Comment: How do you deploy your web application, and what is the site binding information of this client project? try to configure an Http binding to the WCF service, then we can call the service over Http.

Comment: Web application deployed over IIS within application pool, as for binding of the client its ip address with dns.